# HTML: Set Div on load to a second fold

Tags: html, css

I want a div to set a div on load of the page to another fold.

Let's say that I want to have div A on in the viewport on load of the website. Div B should be on the viewport if I scroll down. So that I can use a button to move down to the second div.

I don't want to use margin on div b because it won't be responsive afterwards, right?

I hope that the sample code will make it easier to understand.

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="a"></div>
         <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A margin on what?  Do you have some code that you could post?

Comment: Updated as u suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a `margin-top` to make each div the full viewport.
What you could do is use viewport height instead of a margin to make each `div` take 100% of the viewport.  This is responsive.

```
.a {
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

.b {
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqnc32x2/).

Comment: That's the solution.